# UITableView insert rows without scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a list of data that I'm pulling from a web service.  I refresh the data and I want to insert the data in the table view above the current data, but I want to keep my current scroll position in the tableview.

Right now I accomplish this by inserting a section above my current section, but it actually inserts, scrolls up, and then I have to manually scroll down.  I tried disabling scrolling on the table before this, but that didn't work either.

This looks choppy and seems hacky.  What is a better way to do this?

```
[tableView beginUpdates];

[tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

[tableView endUpdates];

NSUInteger iContentOffset = 200; //height of inserted rows

[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, iContentOffset)];
```

Comment: I'm trying to emulate what what most Twitter apps do.  They put a separator between the old and new data (indicating there is new data) and allow you to scroll through the timeline in chronological order.

Comment: Have you tried `scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated:` or `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` after inserting?

Comment: Could you explain why `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` and `scrollToNearestRow...` don't work for you? EDIT: Hah, Nick beat me.

Comment: @Nick @Josh I can accomplish this scrolling using `setContentOffset:` but my real question is how to avoid scrolling in the first place.  Also, both those options worked worse than `setContentOffset:` from what I've tried.

Comment: Just to understand this: You are at index 13 for example, and like to insert a row at 3 and this should not scroll and keep the pos at 13, right?

Comment: @Nick Correct.  (I'm inserting a section, but the behavior is the same)

Comment: Hm, I don't know a lot about iOS, but on the Mac I would look for a way to scroll back to where I was, (trusting (but verifying!) it to be fast enough), rather than a way to not scroll at all. Sorry...

Comment: Strange, I've just created a simple tableView and inserted rows as well as sections at index 0 and wherever the pos is, the old cells get pushed down, but no scrolling up! The animation type is ignored, whether with begin/endUpdates or without.

Comment: So yeah, the table doesn't actually scroll up, it keeps the previous position.  Relative to the existing rows though, it scrolls.  I guess I didn't explain that so well.

Comment: Does an animation occur though you've set it to none?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way I found to get my desired behavior is to not animate the insertion at all.  The animations were causing the choppyness.

Instead I am calling:

```
[tableView reloadData];

// set the content offset to the height of inserted rows 
// (2 rows * 44 points = 88 in this example)
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 88)];
```

This makes the reload appear at the same time as the content offset change.

Comment: This still poses a problem when the table view is not full... any ideas?

Answer (score 17):

If I understand your mission correctly,

I did it in this way:

```
if(self.tableView.contentOffset.y > ONE_OR_X_ROWS_HEIGHT_YOUDECIDE
{

    self.delayOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    self.delayOffset = CGPointMake(self.delayOffset.x, self.delayOffset.y+ insertedRowCount * ONE_ROW_HEIGHT);

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [self.tableView setContentOffset:self.delayOffset animated:NO];    


}else
{
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPath:indexPathArray   WithRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

}
```

With this code, If user is in the middle of the table and not the top, the uitableview will reload the new rows without animation and no scrolling.
If user is on the top of the table, he will see row insert animation.

Just pay attention in the code, I'm assuming the row's height are equal, if not , just calculate  the height of all the new rows you are going to insert.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

For further spectators looking for a **Swift 3+** solution:

You need to save the current offset of the `UITableView`, then reload and then set the offset back on the `UITableView`.

```
func reloadTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) {
    let contentOffset = tableView.contentOffset
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
}
```

Called by: `reloadTableView(self.tableView)`

Comment: How to do when adding new rows at top?

Answer (score 1):

Just call `setContentOffset` before `endUpdates`, that works for me.

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, iContentOffset)];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using self sizing cells and the estimated row height was pretty useless because the cells can vary significantly in size. So calculating the contentOffset wasn't working for me.

The solution that I ended up with was quite simple and works perfectly.
So first up I should mention that I have some helper methods that allow me to get the data element for an index path, and the opposite - the index path for a data element.

```
-(void) loadMoreElements:(UIRefreshControl *) refreshControl {
  NSIndexPath *topIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
  id topElement = [myModel elementAtIndexPath:topIndexPath];

  // Somewhere here you'll need to tell your model to get more data
  [self.tableView reloadData];

  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myModel indexPathForElement:topElement];

  [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                        atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                                animated:NO];

  [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers here really worked for me, so I came up with my solution. The idea is that when you pull down to refresh a table view (or load it asynchronously with new data) the new cells should silently come and sit on top of the tableview without disturbing the user's current offset. So here goes a solution that works (pretty much, with a **caveat**)

```
var indexpathsToReload: [IndexPath] = [] //this should contain the new indexPaths
var height: CGFloat = 0.0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {

        self.tableview.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0) as IndexSet, with: .none) 
        self.tableview.layoutIfNeeded()
        indexpathsToReload.forEach({ (idx) in
            height += self.feed.rectForRow(at: idx).height
        })
        let afterContentOffset = self.tableview.contentOffset                             
        let newContentOffset = CGPoint(x: afterContentOffset.x, y: afterContentOffset.y + height)
        self.tableview.setContentOffset(newContentOffset, animated: false)
    }
}
```

**CAVEAT (WARNING)**
This technique will not work if your tableview is not "full" i.e. it only has a couple of cells in it. In that case you would need to also increase the `contentSize` of the tableview along with the `contentOffset`. I will update this answer once I figure that one out.

**EXPLANATION**:
Basically, we need to set the `contentOffset` of the `tableView` to a position where it was before the reload. To do this we simply calculate the total height of all the new cells that were added using a pre populated `indexPath` array (can be prepared when you obtain the new data and add them to the datasource), these are the `indexPaths` for the new cells. We then use the total height of all these new cell using `rectForRow(at: indexPath)`, and set that as the `y` position of the `contentOffset` of the `tableView` after the reload. The `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` is not necessary but I put it there because I just need to give the tableview some time to bounce back to it's original position since I am doing it on a "pull to refresh" way. Also note that in my case the `afterContentOffset.y` value is always `0` so I could have hard coded `0` there instead.

Comment: Great answer. `layoutIfNeeded` is the key here. I wouldn't bother too much about the "tableView not full" scenario. If the content doesn't fill the whole screen, inserting more data will not make the tableView scroll in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with self-sizing cells. Neither `contentSize` nor `contentOffset` are stable, predictable values, in that case. Perhaps one has more luck with a `UICollectionViewController` making it look like a table view.

Comment: @DrMickeyLauer yes you are correct. The solution doesn’t work with dynamic height cells. I was able to achieve this by calculating the heightForRow but since it can’t be done in a background thread it’s a little laggy when it does the calculation. Your Collection view comment is right, since it’s more powerful than a TableView, you might want to take a look at Instagram’s IGListKit.  It takes a little while to fully understand how IGListKit works in the beginning but it can do a whole bunch of things.

Comment: One caveat with IGListKit is that it could be quite a bit of work to refactor an existing code to use IGListKit since it uses UICollectionView only and the implementation is quite different than the built in Collection view.