# UITableView scrolling on insert

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am dealing with a web service that uses paging. I am using UITableView to display results. The idea is once the user scrolls to somewhere around the bottom of the table, a call is made to get new data. Once received the data is inserted into table view, with normal, [tableView beginUpdates] , [tableView inserItemsAtIndexPahts..] and [tableView endUpdates]. The issue, is  if the table view is decelerating, and the cells are inserted at the same time, the deceleration animation will stop immediately making the table view seem 'weird'.

Any way around this problem ?

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872759/uitableview-insert-rows-without-scrolling

Comment: The issue is not that it scrolls on insert but rather that it stops decelerating.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your table view when it stopped decelerating by implementing `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` method. And do not insert into table view anything when it's decelerating.

```
if (tableView.decelerating == NO) {
    // Insert.
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did figure it out myself, but it would be cool to be able to just load items as user approaches the end and just let him scroll through as if the items were there all the time, and not wait for the update until he/she stops scrolling.

Comment: Try to use `[tableView reloadData];` instead of `[tableView beginUpdates] .. [tableView insertItemsAtIndexPaths..] .. [tableView endUpdates]`. Maybe it'll help.