# UITableView Refresh without scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `_TableView` with items , and I want to set automatic refresh,and I don't want it to scroll on refresh , lets say user scrolled 2 pages down , and the refresh trigered -> so I want to put the refreshed content to the top of the table without interupting user's scrolling

Assume user was on row 18 
and now the `_dataSource` is refreshed so it fetched lets say 4 items , so I want user to stay on the item he was.

What would be the best approach to achieve it ??

Comment: hope those answers will help you:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872759/uitableview-insert-rows-without-scrolling/11585557#11585557

Comment: Does your tableview cell has static height or dynamic height ? cause if your table view has dynamic cell height its impossible to reload without scrolling , Table view has to re create all the cell from the scratch when it has dynamic cell  .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am showing if only one row is being added. You can extend it to multiple rows.

```
    // dataArray is your data Source object
    [dataArray insertObject:name atIndex:0];
    CGPoint contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
    contentOffset.y += [self tableView:self.tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:contentOffset];
```

But for this to work you need to have defined `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` the method. Or else, you can directly give your tableview row height if it is constant.

Comment: It is not constant , and thanks for your answer I will try it ,

Comment: Yes then surely you have defined the method of `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Accept my answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 54):

For **Swift 3+**:

You need to save the current offset of the `UITableView`, then reload and then set the offset back on the `UITableView`.

I have created this function for this purpose:

```
func reload(tableView: UITableView) {

    let contentOffset = tableView.contentOffset
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)

}
```

Simply call it with: `reload(tableView: self.tableView)`

Comment: What if the tableview doesn't change the offset still loads the new cells?

Comment: @RockBalbao - I don't understand your question bro

Comment: I am using NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate. Now I am using UIRefreshControl to load old cells on scrollDown. On performFetch the data is loaded I need to do only reload data. but I don't want to show reloaded cells in. Let them load above. When I scroll above then only they become visible. So to implement this I tried using this contentOffset way. but before reloadData and after reloadData the contentOffset is same though it added few rows above

Comment: I don't feel like your implementation has much to do with this. Because having contentOffset to be the same before and after reloadData is exactly the point. This here is useful for example if you have a "like button" and you're using a real time data base. To prevent the tableView from shaking. I'd recommend to just open a thread here on stack and describe your problem as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 27):

**SWIFT 3**

```
let contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
self.tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
```

This is error of iOS8 when using UITableViewAutomatic Dimension. We need store the content offset of table, reload table, force layout and set contenOffset back.

```
CGPoint contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
[self.tableView setContentOffset:contentOffset];
```

Comment: That first line about iOS 8 save my day.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Code.

Comment: Saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer makes sense if you have 50 rows, each 30 points high first, then 3 rows each 3 points high after. Imagine you scroll to the bottom and reload data - you just can't remain at the same scroll offset after.

Answer (score 11):

Just set `estimatedRowHeight` to maximum possible value.

```
 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1000
 self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 100.0
 self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 500.0
```

That's it!!

### Note:

Please do not use `FLT_MAX, DBL_MAX` value. May be it will crash your app.

Comment: Worked for me perfectly

Comment: Worked for me perfectly

Comment: This also worked perfectly for me, tx! I linked this answer from another question about the same subject.

Answer (score 5):

Use Extension

create `UITableViewExtensions.swift` and add following:

```
extension UITableView {

    func reloadDataWithoutScroll() {
        let offset = contentOffset
        reloadData()
        layoutIfNeeded()
        setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing it this way:

```
messages.insertContentsOf(incomingMsgs.reverse(), at: 0)
table.reloadData()

// This is for the first load, first 20 messages, scroll to bottom
if (messages.count <= 20) {
      let indexToScroll = NSIndexPath(forRow: saferSelf.messages.count - 1, inSection: 0)
      table.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexToScroll, atScrollPosition: .Top , animated: false)
}
// This is to reload older messages on top of tableview
else {
      let indexToScroll = NSIndexPath(forRow: incomingMsgs.count, inSection: 0)
      table.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexToScroll, atScrollPosition: .Top , animated: false)
      // Remove the refreshControl.height + tableHeader.height from the offset so the content remain where it was before reload
      let theRightOffset = CGPointMake(0, table.contentOffset.y - refreshControl.frame.height - table.headeView.frame.height)
      table.setContentOffset(theRightOffset, animated: false)
}
```

...also, since I use dynamic cell height, to avoid some weirdness, the estimation is cached:

```
var heightAtIndexPath = [NSIndexPath: CGFloat]()
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return heightAtIndexPath[indexPath] ?? UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    heightAtIndexPath[indexPath] = cell.frame.height
}
```

Comment: In my case cell caching is the only thing that has worked, thanks ! :)

Comment: Thanks for great suggestion on caching height estimation! @Marco

Answer (score 4):

In `iOS 12.x`, using `Xcode 10.2.1`, an easier option is.

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation { 
    let loc = tableView.contentOffset
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    tableView.contentOffset = loc
}
```

This works better than following; it shakes at times when the row is not fully visible.

```
let contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
self.tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2 :** Simple Solution

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0
 self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
 self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
}

//And then simply update(insert, reloadSections, delete etc) your tableView or reload

tableView.reloadData()

//or

UIView.performWithoutAnimation {

  tableView.beginUpdates()
  .....
  tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to reload you have to

```
self.tableView.reloadData()

self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

and also use this `UITableViewDelegate`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 'your maximum cell's height'
}
```

and your tableView will remain on the previous scroll position without scrolling

Answer (score 1):

This code will prevent unnecessary animation and maintain the scroll view's content offset, it worked fine for me.

```
let lastScrollOffset = tableView.contentOffset
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.endUpdates()
tableView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
tableView.setContentOffset(lastScrollOffset, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

`reloadData` with

`tableView.reloadRows`(`at: tableView!.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none`),

but you should be care about `no cells`, if `no cells`, this method should cause crash.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote something that works perfect for me:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func reloadDataAndKeepContentOffsetInPlace(reloadData:(() -> Void)) {
    let currentContentHeight = contentSize.height
    if currentContentHeight == .zero {
       reloadData()
       return
    }
    reloadData()
    layoutIfNeeded()
    let newContentHeight = self.contentSize.height
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        var contentOffset = self.contentOffset
        contentOffset.y += newContentHeight - currentContentHeight
        self.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
    }
  }
}
```

use like this:

```
   self.reloadSomeData()
   collectionView.reloadDataAndKeepContentOffsetInPlace { [weak self] in
                                guard let self = self else { return }
                                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```swift
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0
tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/86703